# Stumped re: Chrome iOS Behavior

Tags: ios, google-chrome, dns

I'm totally stumped and hoping someone can help.  My site works fine on:

- Desktop chrome
- Desktop safari
- Desktop firefox
- iOS safari

But when trying to access the site on iOS chrome, I get the following:

"Warning! Something's not right here!"  (Screenshot attached)
[image]

There is very little details for debugging:

"Chrome is unable to verify that the URL for the site is correct. Unverified URL".

I'm not sure what information is required to hep debug this.

The `www.` site is hosted on Heroku - I have a CNAME redirect from `www.retirementplan.io` to `appname.herokuapp.com`.

I'm using [xDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) on the site, which does some iFrame stuff...... Site is pretty standard Ruby on Rails.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help you could provide would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the Data Compression Proxy turned on? If so, try turning it off.

Comment: Do you mean through Nginx? Or in rails? I'm not 100% sure what you are asking about :)

Comment: Data Compression Proxy is a Google Chrome feature on mobile operating systems, like iOS and Android.

Comment: @PhistucK - Chrome's "Reduce Data Usage" is off.

Comment: Same Problem here on iOS Chrome. Interestingly, we are also using [xDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain). Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Sam I was only able to fix this by tearing out xDomain - as you can see I didn't get any better suggestions.  I'll answer the question and bring up an issue with the xDomain team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with xDomain.  By removing that library, it is now working fine.

**EDIT**

This is now fixed with [xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) version `0.6.13`.

Comment: can you test again please at http://jpillora.com/xdomain on an iPhone? XDomain 0.6.13 **should** fix this bug.

Comment: @jpillora - Thanks for following up! Unfortunately I've gone totally a different direction, and no longer have this on my app.  No way to test it :(

Comment: Thats okay, though could you update your answer with "Fixed in XDomain 0.6.13"? (Edit: as long as you have an iPhone, you should be able to confirm this at http://jpillora.com/xdomain)

Comment: I visited that site using Chrome on iOS, and it appears to work now. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

For us removing XDomain unfortunately isn't an option, and the [workaround](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain/issues/76#issuecomment-43106185) given on the project's issue page potentially has a lot of side effects.

We have decided to avoid loading XDomain altogether for non-IE browsers. This means we either load XDomain dynamically, or we do browser dependent content loading ([apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#browser-dependent-content), [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_browser_module.html)). In our case loading XDomain dynamically means we need to load a whole lot of other code dynamically, so we prefer to do the latter.

Comment: Was looking into this again, see [this comment](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain/issues/76#issuecomment-48842169), I think the result will be the same though - wait until Chrome passes its checks, then `xhook.enable()` - still will require delaying app load. Please post on https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain/issues/76 if you find a good solution :)

Comment: I am getting the same issue in php website.